# Problems using PIL 1.1.7

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

The trivial

```
import Image
im = Image.OPEN('C:\abc.bmp')
```

results in the following exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    im = Image.OPEN('C:\Documents and Settings\umair.ahmed\My Documents\My Pictures\avanza.bmp')
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

not sure if i am missing something, kindly help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
Image.open()
```

It's case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the error message came from your input, because the file names are different, but you should not use `'C:\abc.bmp'`, in your `open()` call, but use either `C:/abc.bmp`, or `r'C:\abc.bmp'`.  Backslash is an escape character in Python.

Comment: yep i changed 'c:\abc.bmp' to 'c:\\abc.bmp' but the main problem was as @Swingley suggested. Thanx for suggesting r'c:\abc.bmp' its far more convenient.